# Dynamic Programming: Minimizing whitespace

Tags: dynamic-programming

This is a homework question, but I am completely lost.  I am having an impossible time figuring out what the subproblem is: I've tried a greedy approach, I've tried building up the number of words on a line, etc. and I can't come up with anything.  Can anyone offer any insight at all?

Problem:  Consider a program that converts a list of words into typset text.  The program prints the words onto lines of length W such that the amount of extra spaces at the end of the  line such that a line containing words i through j contains W - j + i - SUM(characters in words i thru j).  Write a dynamic programming algorithm that minimizes the sum of squares of extra spaces on each line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the approach you are supposed to have is the following:

->find the best solution for a line of length 1 and save the value.(this should be trivial).

->find the best solution for a line of length 2 this way:

for every word see if they fit. if they do calculate the remaining space and use the best solution for that space (will be 1 or 0 space left).

...(do this all the way to W)

->find the best solution for a line of length W this way:

for every word see if they fit. If they do, calculate the remaining space and use the best solution for that remaining space (since it is less than W you have already calculated it.)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming is a good choice to solve such problems in easy way for a developer.

A dynamic programming approach that we can use to solve this problem is as follows. First, if all words fit on one line, then we are done.
            If not, then we will try all possible combinations that could possibly fit on this one line, then we solve the subproblem that consists of the
           remaining words for each possible combination, we can find the best layout by minimizing the cost of the first line and adding the minimum
           cost of the remaining subproblem.

> Let MAX(i) be the largest j for which
>   [image] , meaning that word j could fit on the line starting with word i.
>               We can fill an n-element array of costs c, where c[i] is the minimal cost of printing words i through n, as follows:
>               If MAX(i) = n, then c[i] = 0 else :     [image]
>               
>   Filling the array top to bottom from n to 1, will take O((M/2)n) time, since at most M/2 words can fit on a single line. The space required is O(n).